# Is it possible to prevent terminal from hanging after running a tkinter program

Tags: python, tkinter

I have written a tkinter program but anytime I run the program, the terminal hangs. Is there any way in python to add to the program that will prevent terminal from hanging whilst the tkinter program is still running like in the last part? Any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks in advance

```
### Terminal hangs without showing the working directory ####

PS C:\Users\DANIEL\Desktop\exp\fcnvmb\results> python3 c:/Users/DANIEL/Desktop/exp/fcnvmb/GUI.py

*******************************************
            START TESTING
*******************************************
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\_reduction.py:42: UserWarning: size_average and reduce args will be deprecated, please use reduction='mean' instead.
  warnings.warn(warning.format(ret))
The testing psnr: 15.81, SSIM: 0.5168 
Testing complete in  0m 2s



#### I want the working directory to show in the terminal whilst the tkinter program is still running like below ####

PS C:\Users\DANIEL\Desktop\exp\fcnvmb\results> python3 c:/Users/DANIEL/Desktop/exp/fcnvmb/GUI.py

*******************************************
            START TESTING
*******************************************
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\_reduction.py:42: UserWarning: size_average and reduce args will be deprecated, please use reduction='mean' instead.
  warnings.warn(warning.format(ret))
The testing psnr: 15.81, SSIM: 0.5168 
Testing complete in  0m 2s
PS C:\Users\DANIEL\Desktop\exp\fcnvmb\results>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use the `pythonw` command instead of `python3`.  It is an identical interpreter, but it is configured as a GUI app instead of a Win32 console app, so that it does not stayed attached to the console.

That, of course, means that you can't write to stdout any more.  There won't BE a stdout.  That's the tradeoff.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But is there a way to do it when running from a GUI like VS code

Comment: You can run `pythonw` in the VSCode terminal pane.  But for things like F5 and Ctrl-F5, no; the IDE needs to have that connection.